# Can I split an existing sub-panel feed to feed a 2nd sub-panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit

I currently have a subpanel that is fed from my main panel with 6ga wire on a 50 amp circuit breaker. Is it OK for me to add in a junction box and split the subpanel feed so that I can feed a spa panel with a 50 amp GFCI circuit breaker?

In short, the 50 amp circuit coming from the main panel would feed a already full sub panel and a 50 amp gfci spa panel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the existing loads? It may be possible but we would need to know the loads and what the actual load of the hot tub, there are few times where this is possible but we would need to know the loads to say for sure.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the existing panel, and how many amps does the spa pull?